# Как игнорировать редирект на https для конкретной директории?

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, редирект

Добавил в `.htacces` следующие строки:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы для папки `mobile_app` редирект не работал.

Информацию в гугле не нашел, буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте одно условие

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
# запрошенный путь не начинается с /mobile_app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile_app
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Спасибо, прописал, жду пока тестировщик проверит. Странный прикол в том, что в этой папке есть свой `.htacces` в котором стоит `RewriteEngine off`, но он не работает...

Comment: Работает, спасибо)