# .htaccess 301 Redirect кроме некоторых адресов

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, apache

Всем привет, есть такой код который делает 301 редирект, а также убирает с url адреса папку site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/site/home [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^site/(.+)$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

А также у меня есть метод Ajax который обращается по этой ссылке

```
example.com/php/ajax.php
```

к php cкрипту, который явно недоволен таким положением дел и работать не хочет, видимо тоже попадая под редирект.

Вопрос в том, как добавить эту ссылку в исключение редиректа ?

Comment: Так же как и тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/700476/186083 отменяется редирект для отдельной папки.

Answer (score 0):

## 301 редирект на все кроме ajax/ajax.php

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ajax/ajax.php
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/site/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Не вижу отличия от того вопроса/ответа.